# iOS - Alamofire RequestRetrier not provoked

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to implement a retry mechanism and i saw that alamofire has one.
I am trying to implement a simple mechanism of retry with number of times for a request , yet something is wrong.

```
class OAuth2Handler: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {
  func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
    return urlRequest
 }

var defaultRetryCount = 4
private  var requestsAndRetryCounts: [(Request, Int)] = []
private  var lock = NSLock()

private func index(request: Request) -> Int? {
    return requestsAndRetryCounts.index(where: { $0.0 === request })
}

func addRetryInfo(request: Request, retryCount: Int? = nil) {
    lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }
    guard index(request: request) == nil else { print("ERROR addRetryInfo called for already tracked request"); return }

    requestsAndRetryCounts.append((request, retryCount ?? defaultRetryCount))
}

func deleteRetryInfo(request: Request) {
    lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }
    guard let index = index(request: request) else { print("ERROR deleteRetryInfo called for not tracked request"); return }

    requestsAndRetryCounts.remove(at: index)
}

func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion){

    lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }

    guard let index = index(request: request) else { completion(false, 0); return }
    let (request, retryCount) = requestsAndRetryCounts[index]

    if retryCount == 0 {
        completion(false, 0)
    } else {
        requestsAndRetryCounts[index] = (request, retryCount - 1)
        completion(true, 0.5)
    }
 }
}
```

this is the class that i am trying to use this:

```
let sessionManager = SessionManager()

override init() {
    sessionManager.adapter = RequestAdapter.self as? RequestAdapter
    sessionManager.retrier = OAuth2Handler()
}


func sendRequest(url: String,meth: HTTPMethod,parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, success: @escaping (String, Data) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {

    self.asyncSerialWorker.enqueueWork { (done) in
        self.sessionManager.request(url, method:meth).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                print("Generic succsess")
                let value = responseObject.result.value
                let json = JSON(value!)
                guard let result = responseObject.data else {return}
                success(self.parser.parseMaiden(json: json), result)
            }

            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!

                print("login failed")
                failure(error)
            }
            done()
        }
    }
}
```

if there are any other suggestions i would love to hear them

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue her was to add the request to the retry, so first i did this:

```
let sessionManager = SessionManager()
var retrier = OAuth2Handler()

override init() {
    sessionManager.retrier = retrier
}
```

and in the call itself i did as follow:

```
func sendRequest(url: String,meth: HTTPMethod,parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, success: @escaping (String, Data) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
    let request = sessionManager.request(url, method: meth, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    retrier.addRetryInfo(request: request)

    self.asyncSerialWorker.enqueueWork { (done) in
        self.sessionManager.request(url, method:meth).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                print("Generic succsess")
                let value = responseObject.result.value
                let json = JSON(value!)
                guard let result = responseObject.data else {return}
                success(self.parser.parseMaiden(json: json), result)
            }

            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!

                print("login failed")
                failure(error)
            }
            done()
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see i have add to the retry a request :

```
              retrier.addRetryInfo(request: request)
```

maybe i should do a remove in success(will check and update)

Answer (score 0):

`sessionManager.adapter = RequestAdapter.self as? RequestAdapter` seems very wrong. You should be setting it to an instance of your `OAuth2Handler`.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: It should likely be `sessionManager.adapter = OAuth2Handler()`.

Comment: Ok so i got it.
i will post my answer